# iOS 14 ARKit CapturedImage JPEG Conversion HEIC Warning

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, ios14

**TL;DR: Something has changed with ARKit `capturedImage` in iOS14, and we couldn't make it fit into our flow.**

> Built with Xcode 12 GM, tested on iPhone 6S 14.0.

We have implemented a flow where we transform `ARFrame` to `Data`, which works perfectly for devices that are not upgraded to iOS14 yet.

We are getting the `ciImage` like:

```
extension ARFrame {
    var ciImage: CIImage { CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: capturedImage) }
}
```

which we feed in an `ImageConverter`:

```
public class ImageConverter {
    lazy var imageContext = CIContext(mtlDevice: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)
    lazy var colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)

    public func jpgData(for image: CIImage) -> Data {
        guard let colorSpace = colorSpace else { return Data() }

        if let jpegRepresentation = imageContext.jpegRepresentation(of: image,
                                                                    colorSpace: image.colorSpace ?? colorSpace) {
            return jpegRepresentation
        } else {
            return Data()
        }
    }
}
```

So, the problem is, when we call `.jpegRepresentation`, it gives a warning:

```
findWriterForType:128: unsupported file format 'public.heic'
```

And although the `jpegRepresentation` is not nil, it's not working for our server, which expects a jpeg data (which still works for iOS13.7 or below devices).

What we tried so far:

```
if let heifRepresentation = imageContext.heifRepresentation(of: image,
                                                            format: .RGBA8,
                                                            colorSpace: image.colorSpace ?? colorSpace) {
    return heifRepresentation
}
```

returns nil, and throws the same error with `.jpegRepresentation`. Also tried other formats, to no avail.

Comment: I am getting same error. Cross-posted here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64216068/heic-encoding-of-ciimage-failing-with-ios14

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64216068/heic-encoding-of-ciimage-failing-with-ios14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem lies within the created JPEG data format with `.jpegRepresentation`.**

Here's the difference between iPhone XS - iOS13 vs iPhone 6S - iOS14:

*Terminal Output:*

> ➜ file testiOS13.jpeg
>
> testiOS13.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF
> standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 72x72, segment length 16, Exif
> Standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=1], baseline,
> precision 8, 600x800, components 3

> ➜ file testiOS14.jpeg
>
> testiOS14.jpeg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data,
> big-endian, direntries=5, xresolution=74, yresolution=82,
> resolutionunit=2], baseline, precision 8, 412x733, components 3

**JFIF Standard 1.01 is missing on iOS 14 ARKit pictures.**

With a hoop between `CGImage` and `Data` (and an availability check in case something goes amiss with iOS 13.7 or below):

```
public func jpgData(for image: CIImage, with size: CGSize) -> Data {
    guard #available(iOS 14.0, *) else { return jpgData(for: image) }

    guard let cgImage = imageContext.createCGImage(image, from: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)) else { return jpgData(for: image) }

    let data = NSMutableData()

    guard let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data, AVFileType.jpg as CFString, 1, nil) else { return jpgData(for: image) }
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, cgImage, nil)

    guard CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination) else { return jpgData(for: image) }

    return data as Data
}

private func jpgData(for image: CIImage) -> Data {
    guard let colorSpace = colorSpace else { return Data() }

    return imageContext.jpegRepresentation(of: image, colorSpace: colorSpace) ?? Data()
}
```

With the latest change:

*Terminal Output:*

> ➜ file testiOS14_New.jpeg
>
> testiOS14_New.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard
> 1.01, aspect ratio, density 72x72, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=1], baseline, precision 8,
> 413x734, components 3

Comment: I believe that UIImage `jpgData` itself is broken.